# Android: Text not centering inside textView?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

**Edit:** Sorry ther was a problem in my implementation, the layout weight wasn't adding up to 1 and hence the problem. It worked after I fixed the layoutWeight.

I don't know why but I am unable to center text inside this [custom TextView](https://github.com/Malinskiy/android-material-icons), can someone please help. I tried a variety of things but none is working. The icon inside my IconTextView is closer to the right and not in center. Thanks !!

```
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.25">

          <com.malinskiy.materialicons.widget.IconTextView 
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="{zmdi-play}"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    app:hacky_preview="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share screenshot .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

to your `IconTextView` element

Answer (score 0):

It's not a proper solution but, since maybe the problem is in the implementation of the IconTextView, you could try setting the IconTextView with to `wrap_content` and centering the whole IconTextView inside the wrapping LinearLayout. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.malinskiy.materialicons.widget.IconTextView 
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
            android:text="{zmdi-play}"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:hacky_preview="true" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Text view in relative relative layout like below code

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<com.malinskiy.materialicons.widget.IconTextView 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:text="{zmdi-play}"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:hacky_preview="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: can't do this, i am using layout weights

Comment: You can add relative layout inside linear layout .and then can assigne weight to linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <com.malinskiy.materialicons.widget.IconTextView 
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="{zmdi-play}"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                app:hacky_preview="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this.. may help you..